# The multi-part identifier "t16.nvarchar1" could not be bound

Tags: 2007, list, caml-query

MOSS2007 with SP3.

I have a list with many items. 
From code I get items using simple criteria. (give me all products that have DeliveryDate between in a specific time interval and the field Customer not null)
For this I build a CAML query and use it in code (mList.GetItems(query)).

Before having 2000 items all was OK.

Now I have 2077 items and the error that I receive is “Unknown SQL Exception 4104 occured. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  The multi-part identifier "t16.nvarchar1" could not be bound.”

Checked on the internet and hoped that a last service pack will solve the problem.
But problem persist.
Checked the same simple query in CAML Builder.... same error.
If I remove items until I have only 1999 in the list the issue is gone.

What can I do?

Now in the UI I did a new View that will display all items (set RowLimit to 5000 to be sure) and this work ok, all items are displayed. - I cannot use this view in code because I have to add dinamicaly difrent filter criterias.

But I need to return items in code....so again what is to be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems there is a problem with a lookup field of type "User". If this field is used in filter criteria and also in OrderBy I receive the error.

Now my workaround is to get the items without any OrderBy criteria. After that put them into a DataTable and create a DataView from this. Then I use Sort method from DataView to have the items sorted. Then using a foreach I go to each DataRowView and display the required field values.